# Sitecore 8 WFFM input fields not showing in normal mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I am trying to setup the Web forms for Marketers (WFFM) module in Sitecore 8.1. I can perfectly build a form and insert it in the experience editor, but as soon as I publish it to the page and look at it from a users perspective, the input fields are missing

[image: How it looks in the experience editor]

The first picture is how it looks while editing the page in the experience editor, while the next on is what happens when the page is published.

[image: How it looks in user mode]

Are there anybody who knows what causes this?

Comment: Did you publish on danish language using publish related items?

Comment: It is not language versioned, if that is what you are looking for? The form is in english, and it is inserted on an english page. The reason for the danish, is just that I am fooling around.

Comment: What version  of Sitecore are using ?

Comment: It is Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207) with Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160304

Comment: Looks like a publishing issue. You might have to publish the form individually from the content editor rather than rely on related items publish. See this kb article - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/926033

Comment: Thanks @IanGraham, it worked.

Comment: Great! I've added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a publishing issue and you'll have to publish the form separately using the Content Editor.

Think there is an issue with publish using the related items option and WFFM. See the following knowledge base article:

http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/926033